# How can I make pyenv work properly in Windows?

Tags: python, pyenv

I have installed `pyenv-win`, and now I try to use different versions of Python for my development. I have installed Python 3.10.0 in Windows and set environment variables properly.

Now I have installed Python 3.9.6 with `pyenv` and executed `pyenv local 3.9.6` and when I execute `pyenv which python`, it outputs `3.9.6 (set by C:\Users\alipi\OneDrive\Desktop\Codes\ecommerse\.python-version)`.

When I execute the following code in the Python shell,

```py
>>> import sys
>>> sys.executable
>>> 'C:\\Users\\alipi\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\python.exe'
```

Python must refer to Python 3.9.6. How can I fix it?

Comment: What do you mean by "in shell"? How exactly do you run  python in order to get that result?

Comment: I just type python in the terminal and enter the the code above

Comment: Ah, I understand now. The question is about how to make `pyenv-win` set things up properly so that `python` launches the same version reported by `pyenv which python`. Did you try reading the [documentation](https://pyenv-win.github.io/pyenv-win/)?

Comment: I want to use python 3.9.6 that I have locally set with `pyenv` but It runs python 3.10.0 that I have installed globally in windows

Comment: I have used `pyenv` in Linux and I didn't have any problem with it. The only difference in windows is that I should use `pyenv rehash` after changing my python version.

Answer (score 3):

Try using executables `python3` instead of `python`.

Answer (score -2):

A question like this doesn’t make any sense and is most likely a question that is being asked by someone who doesn't understand the difference between venv or pyenv or the Python shell.

Simple answer:  Get out of the Python shell.  There isn't any reason to be using the Python shell at this time.

You should be using the command prompt or [PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell) (old school).  Then wherever these tools open, use [cd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cd_(command)) (change directory) or *cd..* (backwards) to navigate to the C drive.  Once there, make a new directory for where you want to play with virtual environments.

```
mkdir MyVEplayground
```

Next use *cd* to navigate to that new directory.

```
C:\MyVEplayground
```

Next, create the virtual environment.  To make things less confusing, just create the virtual environment using the regular *venv* function that is build into Python.

```
python -m someName venv
```

Next, the new virtual environment needs to be activated.  When the new virtual environment was created there was a new sub directory created called (someName) and then there were also some more sub subdirectories added.

Move down to the new subdirectory named *someName* using cd (cmd or PowerShell)

```
cd someName
```

There isn't any reason to go below this folder.  Just remain in this new folder *C:MyVEplayground\someName*.

Then the Cmd prompt or PowerShell to activate this new virtual environment.  Just type the following code.  This which will navigate down to the correct subfolder and then activate this virtual environment—all at the same time without having to go there.

```
.\Scripts\Activate
```

It would be advised to become familiar with the basic *venv* function that is built into Python before using any of Python libraries that involve virtual environments—such as pyvenv, which it appears you are trying to use.  These virtual environment libraries have optional and advanced virtual environment features that are best avoided until after understanding the baked-in venv features.

It's should be really obvious and nearly impossible to miss noticing once this virtual environment has been activated.